# FTP as an External Service

Tags: ftp, services

I need to setup an FTP for a business process but I don't want to set it up on our servers. Is there anybody offering this as a service where I can setup and FTP that both myself and my client can access. Essentially outsourcing the FTP as service.

Comment: Have you tried searching for 'ftp as a service' ? This seems like a recommendation for software/services otherwise

Answer (score 2):

Just buy some web hosting and use the FTP almost all web hosts provide. You might want to ensure they support a structure that allows writing outside the web root, but that's fairly common.